# How can I insert multiple values to the MYSQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO `min01_aggregated_data_800` (`datenum`,`Timestamp`,`QFlag_R6_WYaw`)  VALUES ('734970.002777778','2012-04-11 00:04:00.000','989898') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `datenum`=VALUES(`datenum`);
INSERT INTO `min01_aggregated_data_100` (`datenum`,`Timestamp`,`QFlag_R6_WYaw`)  VALUES ('734970.002777778','2012-04-11 00:04:00.000','989898') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `datenum`=VALUES(`datenum`);
INSERT INTO `min01_aggregated_data_300` (`datenum`,`Timestamp`,`QFlag_R6_WYaw`)  VALUES ('734970.002777778','2012-04-11 00:04:00.000','989898') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `datenum`=VALUES(`datenum`);
```

I'm using the `mysql.connector` package to insert the data to the MySQL

```
self.db = mysql.connector.Connect( host = self.m_host, user = self.m_user, password = self.m_passwd, \
        database = self.m_db, port = int( self.m_port ) )
self.con = self.db.cursor( cursor )

self.con.execute( query ) 
self.db.commit()  
self.db.close()
self.con.close()
```

But I'm getting the following error `Use multi=True when executing multiple statements`

I tried to use the `multi=True` in this case I'm not getting any exception, but the data won't be inserted to the MySQL. How can I insert multiple rows?

Comment: user `for` loop over the rows and in the for loop do `self.con.execute( query )` where query is an insert query for 1 row

Answer (score 0):

I see three options:

1. Send every query to the DB separately:

   ```
   [...]
   self.con.execute(query1)
   self.con.execute(query2)
   self.con.execute(query3)
   [...]
   ```
2. [removed as it didn't apply here]
3. I am not very familiar with this `multi=True`, however; it might be possible that there is a solution which calls the `self.con.nextset()` repeatedly. According to the doc, this is only for multiple result sets, but perhaps it is needed on a multi-query request as well.

Comment: The second solution is not good for me, because I'm inserting to different table.

Comment: @iUngi Ouch, didn't see this. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You have three separate queries, so each one should be run separately, i.e:

```
self.con.execute(query1)
self.con.execute(query2)
self.con.execute(query3)
```